# Sphinx - Breaks utf8 character to space

Tags: php, sphinx

I have a string **seule la présentation**.

When I do a phrase search **"pr"**, sphinx matches this string but it should not as there is no word **pr** present in it.

But when searched for **"pre"**, it does not match.

The problem seems to be with this utf8 character **é**. Sphinx ignores this character while indexing and treats string before this character as a word.

Here is the sample `Sphinx` query with match mode `SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED` :

```
@name: "pr"
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an expert on this, but know with sphinx you have to explicitly list what charactors are considered part of 'words' (everything else is considered seperators), via `charset_table`

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-charset-table.html

So you would need to include these charactor(s) in `charset_table` for them to be indexable (with or without 'folding' to non-dialect chars)

This a wiki page 
http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=charset_tables
that lists some stuff, you may be able to copy/paste.